# Finding ways to move from one location to the other

Tags: combinatorics

To move from $A$ to the places marked by black dots, if in each step it is only allowed to move right or up, how many ways are there to do this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please edit the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. Can you solve the problem for smaller grids? Why do you need to know? How much background in combinatorics do you have? If help us we may be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Denote the black dots from top left to bottom right by $i \in \{0, \dots, 6 \}$, e.g. the $0$-th dot is the highest one.
Now note that if you want to get to the $i$-th dot, you will always need to do exactly 6 steps, each of which is either up or right.

Suppose you always only walk 6 times up. This will do for the first one, but not for the others: To reach the $i$-th dot, you will need to change $i$ of those "up"-steps to "right"-steps.

> Hence the answer should be $\binom{6}{i}$ possibilities to reach $i$-th dot.